# Ternas Pitagóricas en Haskell

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

Necesito realizar un programa en el cual introduzca un número, y me diga las ternas pitágoricas (a,b,c) tales que a sea el número introducido. Esto es;

```
ternasPitagoricas :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
ternasPitagoricas 25 == [(25,60,65),(25,312,313)]
ternasPitagoricas 20 == [(20,15,25),(20,21,29),(20,48,52),(20,99,101)]
```

Lo he intentando de la siguiente forma, pero es muy ineficiente, pues para números bajos funciona, pero cuando piden un número alto no lo llega a realizar.

```
ternasPitagoricas :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
ternasPitagoricas n = [(n,b,c) | c <- [2..n^2], b <- [2..c-1], n^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

Necesito que la función sirva para `ternasPitagoricas 20^100000`,  pero no llego a conseguirlo.

Por si no sabéis lo que es una terna pitagórica : [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terna_pitagórica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terna_pitag%C3%B3rica)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para la próxima vez, intenta que el código se vea como bloque y no como líneas sueltas (Basta seleccionar todas las líneas y seleccionar `Control-K`). Tienes ayuda en https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sabiendo `n`, dando valores a `b` puedes calcular `c` reduciendo la complejidad algorítmica.

Comment: @ChemaCortes  Entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero no sé cómo plantear en `Haskell` lo que me dices. Es decir, no se escribirlo. Muchas gracias, y la proxima vez escribiré todo como un bloque (no sabía cómo se hacía).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si conoces `a` y estás probando valores de `c`, entonces puedes calcular el valor de `b` y evitar probar todos sus valores posibles:

```
b = (round . sqrt . fromIntegral) (c^2 - a^2)
```

Veamos si se puede hacer mejor...

Empezando por las matemáticas, tenemos que para números reales ℝ:

```
∀ a ∈ ℝ , ∃ b,c ∈ ℝ ⇒ a² + b² = c²
```

En cambio, para números enteros ℤ sólo se cumple para algunos casos que son las llamadas *ternas pitagóricas*.

Veamos algunas restricciones que podemos deducir para `b` y `c`:

De `a² + b² = c²`, se ve que `b` será siempre estrictamente menor que `c`: `1 ≤ b < c` que, expresado en haskell sería: `b <- [1..c-1]`.

Así mismo, podemos deducir las siguientes restriciones para `c`: `a < c ≤ (a²+1)/2` que en haskell sería:

```
c <- [a+1..a^2+1 `div` 2]
```

Todo junto:

```
ternasPitagoricas :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
ternasPitagoricas a = [(a,b,c) | c <- [a+1..(a^2+1) `div` 2]
                               , let b = (round . sqrt . fromIntegral) (c^2 - a^2)
                               , a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

Por último, cuando dices:

> Necesito que la función sirva para ternasPitagoricas 20^100000, pero no llego a conseguirlo.

Antes imponerte este objetivonción que *necesitas*, tienes que analizar mejor qué estás pidiendo, empezando por crear una función que funcione para pequeños casos y estudiar cómo es posible escalar para alcanzar objetivos mayores.

El número `20^100000` es un número gigantesco. La función anterior tendría que recorrer todos los números enteros desde este número hasta su cuadrado, `20^200000`, lo que seguramente serían unos cuantos siglos de cálculo.

Pero hay otro problema aún más irresoluble: este número es imposible de representar como número de coma flotante sin usar librerías especializadas. Si te das cuenta, el cálculo de `b` usa `sqrt`, que no es usable para números muy muy grandes.

No conozco formas de calcular más rápido las ternas. Realmente es un problema matemático y aquí estamos para resolver problemas de programación.

Comment: `Muchas gracias`